# In AnyLogic how can I send a message to a specific agent in SEND function?

Tags: anylogic

Usually I select RANDOM as second parameter but by doing so the message is likely to be sent to any agent regardless of its type. For example, in the model there are teachers and students, of which graduate and undergraduate are both states. And I'd like to assign teachers to send messages to students whose state is undergraduate. What should I write in teachers' action?

[Main](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bxIdf.png)

[Student's Stateschart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AhhmS.png)

[Teacher's Stateschart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dlMR3.png)

Comment: Create collections for each type of agents. Then randomly select from each collection. Or `Graduate graduate= randomFrom (graduates);`

Comment: Many thanks for your help. But sorry that I've jsut realized that there are only teachers and students, and that graduate and undergraduate are both states of the latter. Then how can I seperate students by their states?

Comment: You don't mention states in your question. I recommend you completely rephrase your question to provide clarity. Maybe add a screenshot of the statechart and let us know what are the agent populations you have. It seems you have a population of Student type and that type has a statechart with two states: graduate and undergraduate? This is just me guessing based on your comments and not on your question, so it certainly needs to be rephrased.

Comment: Thanks, you're right. I have rephrased my question

Answer (score 0):

Based on your updated question, you can do the following:

`send("msg", randomWhere(main.students, s->s.inState(s.Undergraduate)));`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```
send ("msg", main.undergrads.random());
```

Comment: I tried but somehow the main is inaccessible. I also tried get_Main(), but undergrads isn't a variable but an active object instead. Is there any other means of getting the undergrads?

Comment: It seems you have several problems in the model. You should probably rephrase your question and include more details and screenshots if possible. If you are not able to access the main, it may be because you are trying to access it from an agent type instead of a population of agents, but of course this is just one case. You can try ((Main)getEngine().getRoot()).object

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are. Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.